# Auditd not sending to remote central server

Tags: remote, audit, auditd, centralized-logging

I'm setting up a central server using rsyslog and auditd on CentOS 8. I was following [this guide](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=audit&f=2) on how to send remote audit logs to my central server.

> Note: instead of going to /etc/audisp/, these
> files can be found on /etc/audit/ instead.

So I had these Following configurations on both servers

Client:

/etc/audit/auditd.conf

```
log_format = ENRICHED
name_format = HOSTNAME
```

/etc/audit/plugins.d/au-remote.conf

```
active = yes
```

/etc/audit/audisp-remote.conf

```
remote_server = <remote server IP>
port = 60
```

Central server:

/etc/audit/auditd

```
tcp_listen_port = 60
```

Firewall:

```
60/tcp
```

I have restarted both auditd services on both servers but I got this errors:
[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljP8k.png)

Anything wrong? Or does making audit immutable affect this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the guide works. I reread the audit manual again to check about immutable affecting the configuration. Seems like it does! I rebooted the server, since I set it to immutable and now it works. I though immutable only applies to the rules and they are separate from the configuration.